# C# get DbHandle from SqliteConnection

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I created a C# wrapper for sqlite and using it I am trying to execute a *create* and an *insert* query. I need to use my existing sqlite connection so I wrote a **GetDbHandleFromConnection** function to get the `dbHandle`.

This is the connection to DbHandle converter;

```
    public static IntPtr GetDbHandleFromConnection(SqliteConnection conn)
    {
        var sqlFieldValue = typeof(SqliteConnection)
            .GetField("_sql", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
            .GetValue(conn);

        var inner_sqlFieldValue = sqlFieldValue.GetType()
            .GetField("_sql", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
            .GetValue(sqlFieldValue);

        var handleFieldValue = inner_sqlFieldValue.GetType()
            .GetField("handle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
            .GetValue(inner_sqlFieldValue);

        return (IntPtr)handleFieldValue;
    }
```

This is where I calling it; The application stops at the create table execution and I could not find an error.

```
    public void Process()
    {
        SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DB_PATH + ";Pooling=False;");
        connection.Open();
        var dbHandle = GetDbHandleFromConnection(connection); // get DBhandle
        IntPtr err = IntPtr.Zero;
        // application stops here, without error;
        var x = UnsafeSqliteNativeMethods.sqlite3_exec(dbHandle, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("create table boo (id int, name varchar(255))"), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out err);
        var y = UnsafeSqliteNativeMethods.sqlite3_exec(dbHandle, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("insert into boo values (1, 'Bob')"), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out err);
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Output window:
[image]

Can't I use *GetDbHandleFromConnection* to convert `SqliteConnection` and use it as a `DbHandle`? or is there any issue in *GetDbHandleFromConnection* function?

Appreciate your help!